# How much time does it take for computer to recognize the mouse was clicked?

Tags: performance, hardware

I would like to estimate how much time passes between actual mouse click (or keyboard click) and computer registering "mouse click" event.

Let's take typical configuration, Windows, USB mouse and keyboard and look at the following example - the computer displays a signal and a user clicks mouse. The time between the signal and the click consists of two elements. One is the time that took a user to react to the signal and another one is the time it took for computer to recognize that the mouse was clicked for example. Is there any way to get an estimation on that second part?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we can expect that latency is more like 2ms to 4ms for most wired USB mouse users and 1ms for gamers with higher end mice.

[Here is an anandtech article on it.](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2803/2)

Answer (score -2):

Modern computers will process the data at crazy speeds. Depends on the processor speed, I imagine that the computers built 30 years ago were a lot slower than today's however still relatively quick as we are talking about electrical signals. A guestimate would be 0.0000000000000000000009's.

Comment: Do you have some evidence for this guestimate?

Comment: Even taking a clock speed of 3GHz, as is the case with many Intel Processors out there, and assuming a mouse click response would take a single processor cycle (it definitely takes more), your figure is still a good 10 orders of magnitude too small.

Comment: and I don't doubt that!

Comment: mice are much slower than the CPU itself, and run at a few tens of MHz at most. Even for a 4GHz CPU, the clock will tick every 0.00000000025 seconds, so your guestimate 0.0000000000000000000009 is too good to be true